# Control multiple tableviews in a single view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view nested in a collection view and i'm returning 3 (possibly more in the future) collection view cells and I was wondering if it is possible to present different content in each one of the collection cells? I attached a few screenshots to better understand what I am taking about. Thanks.

[image]

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Homeroom"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "8:15 AM - 9:00 AM"
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    return cell
}
```

Comment: differ your tableviews using `tag` and check tag in each of your datasource methods and delegate methods

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You need set a property for every tableView you have and in `delegate` method compare it like below

```
class Some: UIViewController {
    var firstTableView: UITableView
    var secondTableView: UITableView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        firstTableView = YOUR_FIRST
        secondTableView = YOUR_Second
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            return 2;
        }
        else if tableView == secondTableView {
            return 1;
        }
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            return 2;
        }
        else if tableView == secondTableView {
            return 1;
        }
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOfFirstTableView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        }
        else if tableView == secondTableView {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOfSecondTableView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Homeroom"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "8:15 AM - 9:00 AM"
            cell.selectionStyle = .None
        }
        else if tableView == secondTableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Homeroom"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "8:15 AM - 9:00 AM"
            cell.selectionStyle = .None
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. But if I plan to have more than 2 tableviews could I keep adding else statements?

Comment: Yes you can, you can add any tableviews that you wanna

Comment: I tried implementing your solution for the past couple days but I've ran into a few problems. When I am trying to implement the table view global variable I get a compiler error saying my class has no initializers, so I first tried to force unwrap `!` like so (`var tableView1: UITableView!) (var tableview2: UITableView!)` but that gave me a exc_bad_instruction. So I tried as a optional `?` and that got rid of the fatal error but now no data is shown.  The delegate and datasource are set to VC. Could you help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableViewDelegate / UITableViewDataSource methods with if else conditions or some thing similar

eg.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == table1 { // table1 is a global var for the table

    } else if tableView == table2 {

    }
}
```

But I think it will be very clear if you use separate controller class for each table so you can easily manage the code.

But this depends on what type of data you have. If data is completely unrelated you can just use 3 different controllers.
Or if you can reuse data and codes among 3 tables then you can decide if you wanna use 3 different controllers or to use i class with above method.

eg.

```
let table1Controller = Table1Controller(dataList1)
let table2Controller = Table2Controller(dataList2)
let table3Controller = Table3Controller(dataList3)

table1.delegate = table1Controller
table1.dataSource = table1Controller

table2.delegate = table2Controller
table2.dataSource = table2Controller

table3.delegate = table3Controller
table3.dataSource = table3Controller
```